# Check if HTML tags are balanced, and only whitelisted tags are used in Java

Tags: java, html, validation

I take HTML as an input from the user and store it as a string in JAVA.
A sample HTML input by the user is something like this:

```
<p>
 Follow these instructions: 
 <br><br>
   <code>
    Some code here
   </code>
  <p style='color:red;'> WARNING: Some warning here </p>
</p>
```

I want to validate if all the tags are balanced, and only p,br and code tags are present in the HTML. There seems to be no easy way to accomplish this. I have looked into JTidy, but it provides other unnecessary warnings like doctype is not specified, other than HTML is not valid. Other than that JSoup also doesnot give an error if tags are unbalanced(Although, it can be used to check if only whitelisted tags are used). Is there any library or easy way to check for the validity of the HTML in java?

Comment: If you are fine with not using an external library it should not be to hard to simply count the occurences of all tags and check if the number of opening and closing tags fit and if there are tags in there that you don't want to have. Some Regex like `<([^\\s>/]+)` should do the trick.

Comment: Check this [soup](https://jsoup.org/)

Comment: @VictorGubin As I have already said in the question, I couldn't find any way to check if HTML tags are balanced in Jsoup